# Download remote file using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've a link that gets the image, but the image has been removed, renamed or moved to another place

```
public function index()
{    
    $array = [
         { image:'https://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475139/12768822_g.jpg' },
         { image:'http://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475140/12768824_g.jpg' }
    ]    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
       if(!$contents = file_get_contents($array[$i]['image'])) 
       {
             return 'Not found!';
       else {
        Storage::disk('public')->put('default/teste.jpg', $contents); 
       } 
   }
}
```

if the image no exist then I get this error

`file_get_contents(http://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475140/12768824_g.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

I would link get to return "doesnt' exist" and download file if it does.

Comment: Well, when I goto the url provided in my browser I indeed get a 404. If you can see this image, it's presumably because you are logged into this site and it is not public.

Comment: But I have a array of images and some links I can access the images and another no

Comment: I can access image but in this link but the image has been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling the *warning* properly. You can't just use `!` in your `if / else` statement.

(I'm assuming you're using laravel with the methods above.)

You devise some sort of function / method for it. You could do it like so:

```
private function checkImage($url)
{
    $valid_types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']; // add more valid types that you want and so on
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    try {
        $response = $client->head($url);
        return
            !empty($response->getHeaders()['Content-Type'][0]) &&
            in_array($response->getHeaders()['Content-Type'][0], $valid_types, true);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then finally just use the method in your class:

```
$url = 'https://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475140/12768824_g.jpg';
$exists = $this->checkImage($url);
echo $exists ? 'yay!' : 'does not exist'; // or do the echo inside the function whichever you prefer
```

I used the `->head` method above to just check and not include the body.

Edit:

For the purposes of actually donwloading the file. Just use the same code above, along with your `Storage` saving method to save the image. Using `->get()`:

```
$url = 'https://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475139/12768822_g.jpg';
$valid_types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']; // add more valid types that you want and so on
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
try {
    $response = $client->get($url);
    if (
        !empty($response->getHeaders()['content-type'][0]) &&
        in_array($response->getHeaders()['content-type'][0], $valid_types, true)
    ) {
        Storage::disk('public')->put('default/teste.jpg', $response->getBody()->getContents());
    }

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'does not exist';
}
```

Comment: yep, I've testing in index method so the logic is get image in the link $url = 'https://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475140/12768824_g.jpg' to use file_get_contents($url) and save in local Storage::disk('public')->put('default/teste.jpg', $contents);  I am use Laravel

Comment: for ex in this link https://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475139/12768822_g.jpg i can get image and download in Storage Laravel

Comment: @RafaelMoura here's an example to download the file if it exits, if not, it just simply echo that it does not

Comment: I did the test and I done, thaks for your help friend , here worked as charm

Comment: @RafaelMoura sure glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the file does exist, then this is a permission issue. Check the file's owner and mode are the ones you expect. (edited)

Also, make sure that your PHP is configured with `allow-url-fopen` enabled. This will authorize PHP to open remote files. Read more at https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: I can see and get image look : https://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475139/12768822_g.jpg

Comment: Ok. I have adjusted the answer to mention `allow-url-fopen`.